# Numpy array via QBuffer to QGeometry

Tags: python, qt5, pyside, qt3d, pyside2

My goal is to create a `numpy` array and convert its bytes data to `QBuffer`. I am wondering how to set properly `DataSize`, `ByteStride`, and `Count`. See my code below:

```py
self.mesh = Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer()
self.mesh.setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer.Points)
self.geometry = Qt3DRender.QGeometry(self.mesh)

vertex_data_buffer = Qt3DRender.QBuffer(Qt3DRender.QBuffer.VertexBuffer, self.geometry)
data = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
vertex_data_buffer.setData(QByteArray(data.tobytes()))

self.position_attribute = Qt3DRender.QAttribute()
self.position_attribute.setAttributeType(
    Qt3DRender.QAttribute.VertexAttribute)
self.position_attribute.setBuffer(vertex_data_buffer)
self.position_attribute.setDataType(Qt3DRender.QAttribute.Float)
self.position_attribute.setDataSize(3)  # ??
self.position_attribute.setByteOffset(0)
self.position_attribute.setByteStride(6)  # ??
self.position_attribute.setCount(1000)  # ??
self.position_attribute.setName(
    Qt3DRender.QAttribute.defaultPositionAttributeName())

self.geometry.addAttribute(self.position_attribute)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to fix this.

First of all these two copied below lines are deprecated. They can be removed.

```py
self.position_attribute.setDataType(Qt3DRender.QAttribute.Float)
self.position_attribute.setDataSize(3)
```

One line is added:

```
self.position_attribute.setVertexSize(3)
```

`ByteStride` should be set to `12`. `3` is the number of coordinates and `4` is length of `float32` in bytes. Be aware to set `numpy`'s `array`: `data = np.random.rand(1000, 3).astype(np.float32)`.

```py
self.position_attribute.setByteOffset(0)
self.position_attribute.setByteStride(3*4)
self.position_attribute.setCount(1000)
```